# Issue with xPath results in java

Tags: java, dom, sax

I am having a problem in understanding the behavior of my below code, and until I understand it i am having a hard time trying to fix it. I have isolated the issue down to the simplest code snippet i can that displays the issue:

```
String sourceXML = "<root>\n"
            + "<Rule test=\"1\"/>\n"
            + "<Rule test=\"2\"/>\n"
            + "</root>";

    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(sourceXML));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);

    NodeList ruleList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Rule");
    System.out.println("Number of Items found : " + ruleList.getLength());

    for (int t = 0; t < ruleList.getLength(); t++) {
        if (ruleList.item(t).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element ruleElement = (Element) ruleList.item(t);
            String xPathToUse = "//Rule/@test";
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList ruleNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathToUse, ruleElement, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("Found " + ruleNodeList.getLength() + " matches to xpath.....");
        }
    }
```

Generates the following output:

```
Number of Items found : 2
Found 2 matches to xpath.....
Found 2 matches to xpath.....
```

My expectation is that each xPath match would be only 1 for each iteration, as i am running the xpath on each element that i have extracted from the source XML. The output i would expect is:

```
Number of Items found : 2
Found 1 matches to xpath.....
Found 1 matches to xpath.....
```

However it appears as though when looping over the nodelist (which is correct - there are 2 in the source), that the xpath is being run on the whole source XML each time, even though i thought i extracted each node and am just running the xpath on that.

Can anybody help me with understanding what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: you put xpath evaluation inside a loop right? is that why you are getting what you are getting?

Comment: Correct - it is in the loop as i was hoping for it to evaluate on each Node in the NodeList that i am iterating, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: that is because //rule is an absolute path... it basically guarantees that the evaluation will start from the root of the xml doc... try use ./@test... see what happens...